# Connection between number of roots for a given polynomial and its degree

Tags: polynomials, soft-question, roots

Why do we get $2$ solutions for a quadratic equation and $3$ solutions for a cubic equation and $4$ for biquadratic equation and so forth?

Comment: "At most..." . A polynomial equation of degree $\;n\;$ has at most $\;n\;$ *different* solutions in some given **field**. This has to do with the fact that $\;F[x]\;,\;\;F\;$ a field, is an Euclidean domain and thus UFD and etc.

Comment: @DonAntonioyou are wrong, solutions are not always different. An equation can have 3 solutions but same!

Comment: Funny, I thought *you were* the one who asked. Never mind: I am not wrong (and apparently you didn't read all what I wrote or you didn't understand) , but if you decide I am then enjoy.

Comment: Related (although not the same): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25822/how-to-prove-that-a-polynomial-of-degree-n-has-at-most-n-roots and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219115/how-do-i-prove-that-a-polynomial-fx-of-degree-n-has-at-most-n-roots

Answer (score 3):

> Why do we get $2$ solutions for a quadratic equation and $3$ solutions for a cubic equation and $4$ for biquadratic equation and so forth?

This is only true if you allow the solutions to be complex. This is given by [The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), which states (quoted from the Wiki) that

*"...every non-zero, single-variable, degree $n$ polynomial with complex coefficients has, counted with multiplicity, exactly $n$ roots."*

Comment: So if any polynomial have degree of $π$ how many roots will it have?

Comment: @Ramanujan Then it isn't a polynomial, and the fundamental theorem doesn't hold. For it to be a polynomial, you must have non-negative integer exponents only.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem): if $r$ is a root of polynomial $P(x)$, then $P(x)$ must factor as $$P(x) = (x-r)Q(x),$$ where the degree of $Q$ is one less than the degree of $P$.

Then we have $P(x) =0$ if and only if $$(x-r)Q(r) =0,$$ which occurs when $x=r$ or when $x$ is a root of $Q$.  So $P$ has at most one more root than $Q$, or exactly one more if you are willing to count multiple roots multiple times.

Since a 1st-degree polynomial evidently has 1 root, an $n$th-degree polynomial has $n$ roots (or "at most $n$" if you don't count the multiple roots separately.)