# A polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm auditing a number theory course. I'm trying to prove the following:

> A polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots

I know there are *many* proofs of this on SE, however none are particularly accessible (for me, at least). I know a bit of number theory, and a bit of abstract algebra. Any good starting points or hints?

Comment: "None are particularly accessible" how come? Besides, what coefficients do those polynomials have?

Comment: That's not the fundamental theorem of algebra. That theorem says that a *complex* polynomial has *exactly* $n$ roots (if we include multiplicity). So do you need a proof of the claim you wrote, or of the FTOA?

Comment: My apologies. I need a proof of the claim as written.

Comment: I assume that the coefficients are drawn from a field. Argue by induction on the degree. The assertion plainly holds if the degree is 1. Assume the result for all polynomials of degree (n-1) as your induction hypothesis. Now consider a polynomial of degree n. If it has no roots there is nothing to prove. It it has a root, factor it out and use the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prove that a polynomial F\[x\] of degree n has at most n roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219115/how-do-i-prove-that-a-polynomial-fx-of-degree-n-has-at-most-n-roots)

Comment: You might need this  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem and the Unique Factorization Property of a polynomial ring over a field.

Comment: It will be difficult for anyone to answer this if you do not explain what troubles you have understanding those other proofs.

Comment: Do you know polynomial division?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  There's a *factor theorem* saying that if $a$ is a root, then $p(x)$ has $x-a$ as a factor.