# Number of roots smaller than degree of polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, roots

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $f\in R[X]$ a polynomial with $f\neq 0$ and suppose $a_1,...,a_n\in R$ are roots of $f$ with $a_i-a_j\in R^*$ for all $i,j$ with $1\leq i<j\leq n$.

> How do I prove that $n\leq\deg f$?

I have no idea how to do this proof, maybe you can show me how?

Comment: Divide with remainder, $f(X) = (X - a_1)\cdot g(X) + r(X)$, with $\deg r < 1$. Then $f(a_1) = 0$ tells you what $r$ is. Then look whether you can see what the condition on the zeros tells you.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't really see what you did there

Comment: Do you know how to prove that a polynomial $f \in R[X]$ has at most $\deg f$ zeros in $R$ in the case that $R$ is a field?

Comment: @DanielFischer No...

Comment: But $R$ isnt a field here right?

Comment: Right, $R$ is not a field here (it might be, that isn't forbidden, but we can't use anything specific to fields), so we need to adapt the proof, using the extra premises we have here. The answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25822/how-to-prove-that-a-polynomial-of-degree-n-has-at-most-n-roots) may be helpful to understand the proof for a field (more generally, for integral domains, the proof is the same).

Comment: @DanielFischer would you mind posting an answer to show me a proof?

Comment: @user26857 $R^*$ is the group of all units in $R$, do you know what units are?

Comment: @user26857 An element $x$ in a ring is a unit if there exists an element $y\in R$ such that $xy=1$, where $1$ is the identity element of multiplication of $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induction on $n\ge 2$. The base case $n=2$ is left to the readers.

By the induction hypothesis $\deg f\ge n-1$. If $\deg f\ge n$ then there is nothing to prove, so we may assume $\deg f=n-1$. Write $f(X)=b_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\cdots+b_1X+b_0$ with $b_{n-1}\ne0$. We have $f(a_i)=0$ for $1\le i\le n$, that is, $b_{n-1}a_i^{n-1}+\cdots+b_1a_i+b_0=0$ for $1\le i\le n$. Set $$A=\pmatrix{1&1&\dots&1\\a_1&a_2&\dots&a_n\\\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\a_1^{n-1}&a_2^{n-1}&\cdots&a_n^{n-1}}.$$ Then $(b_0\ b_1\ \dots\ b_{n-1})A=0$. But $\det A=\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}(a_j-a_i)\in R^*$, hence $A$ is invertible. Now we get $(b_0\ b_1\ \dots\ b_{n-1})=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Nicely written up. But you could have just as well started this induction at $n = 0$. (The condition for $a_i-a_j$ to be invertible is vacuous for $n \leq 1$, but there is nothing wrong about vacuous condition.)