# Finding trinity of complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

> I want to find all $x_1,x_2,x_3$ that satisfy these three equalities:
>   $$x_1+x_2+x_3=6$$
>   $$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=14$$
>   $$x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3=36$$

So i don't know whether i should solve it using the same techniques i do with normal systems of equations or is there some tricks behind it?

So since I found this problem while doing algebraic problems I think there should be an algebraic solution to it. But I am really lost in this case, I don't knwow how to begin.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Mh, by inspection... then permutation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

Use $$(a+b+c)^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2(ab+bc+ca)$$

and $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)\{(a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ca)\}$$

to find $ab+bc+ca, abc$

Then $a,b,c$ are the roots of $$t^3-(a+b+c)t^2+(ab+bc+ca)t-abc=0$$

Comment: But what is $t$?

Comment: @MathIsTheWayOfLife,  The variable of the cubic equation, whose values are required

Comment: oh right, so it's solvable with what i learned about polynomial in algebra, thank you

Comment: How many solutions do you get ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust,  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25822/how-to-prove-that-a-polynomial-of-degree-n-has-at-most-n-roots

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: this doesn't answer my question, does it ? I mean number of solutions of the system.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Then sorry I didn't get your question.

Answer (score 2):

**The hard way**:

The first equation is that of a plane with normal $(1,1,1)$ and this direction is that of an axis of symmetry of the problem.

We will rotate it to bring it to a $u$ axis, using the similarity transform

$$\begin{cases}x=\sqrt2 u-\sqrt3 v+w,\\y=\sqrt2u+\sqrt3v+w,\\z=\sqrt2u\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -2w.\end{cases}$$

Then

$$x+y+z=3\sqrt2u=6,\\
u=\sqrt2.$$
(A plane perpendicular to $u$.)
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=6(u^2+v^2+w^2)=14,\\v^2+w^2=\frac13.$$
(A cylindre of axis $u$.)
$$x^3+y^2+z^3=18\sqrt2uv^2+18\sqrt2uw^2+6\sqrt2u^3+18wv^2-6w^3\\
=18\sqrt2uv^2+18\sqrt2uw^2+18\sqrt2uu^2-12\sqrt2u^3+18wv^2-6w^3\\
=42\sqrt2u-12\sqrt2u^3+18wv^2-6w^3=36,\\
3wv^2=w^3.
$$
(Three planes intersecting on $u$.)

This gives the six solutions

$$v=\pm\frac1{\sqrt3},w=0\lor v=\pm\frac1{2\sqrt3},w=\pm\frac12,$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}x=2\mp1,\\
y=2\pm1,\\
z=2,\end{cases}$$
or
$$\begin{cases}x=2\mp\dfrac12\pm\dfrac12,\\
y=2\pm\dfrac12\pm\dfrac12,\\
z=2\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mp1.\end{cases}$$

As expected, the six permutations of $(1,2,3)$.