# Some linear independence proof involving real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

If the equalities $$\lambda_0a_i⁰+...+\lambda_{n-1}a_i^{n-1}=0,\quad i=1,...,n$$ hold for fixed distinct real $a_i$, how can we conclude $\lambda_i=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: The polynomial $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \lambda_j x^j$ cannot have more than $n-1$ roots, because its degree is $n-1$. Hence it must be the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant fact here is the following:

> **Theorem**: if
>   $$p(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^n \lambda_k x^k$$
>   is a non-trivial degree $n$ polynomial, then $p(x) = 0$ has at most $n$ solutions.

For a proof, see [this other post on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/25822/9754). As your "polynomial" has $n$ roots but its degree is less than $n$, so it's the constant zero function.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $V$ with entries $[V]_{ij} = a_i^{j-1}$ is known as the [Vandermonde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) matrix and has non zero determinant.

Hence if $\lambda=(\lambda_0,\cdots, \lambda_{n-1})^T$ and $V \lambda = 0$ we must have $\lambda = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is much more cumbersome than @Crostul 's explanation, but maybe can help too

You have a linear system of the form
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
1 &a_1 & a_1^2 &\cdots &a_1^{n-1}\\
1 &a_2 & a_2^2 &\cdots &a_2^{n-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 &a_n & a_n^2 &\cdots &a_n^{n-1}\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
\cdot
\left(\begin{matrix}
\lambda_0\\
\lambda_1\\
\vdots\\
\lambda_{n-1}\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(\begin{matrix}
0\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

So there is only the trivial solution ($\lambda_i=0$ $\forall i$) iff the squared matrix is invertible.

Now, that matrix (or its transpose, not sure but it doesn't matter) is usually called a Van der Monde matrix, let's say $V(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$. Using induction it can be proven that
$$\det(V(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n))=\prod_{1\le i <j \le n} (\lambda_i - \lambda_j)$$
which is not zero iff all the $\lambda_k$ are different (and iff the matrix is invertible).