# Prove that if $lx^2+mx+n$ is equal to zero for three distinct values then $l=m=n=0$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

How should I go around to prove that if
$lx^2+mx+n$ equals to zero for three distinct values of $x$, then $l=m=n=0$?

I tried letting $P(x)=lx^2+mx+n$ and used the factor theorem, but I can't seem to reveal the result.

Comment: A polynomial of degree $d$ with coefficients in a field has at most $d$ roots.

Comment: Hint: [Fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

Comment: More explicitly, if $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, with root $r$ [i.e. where $f(r) = 0$], then there exists a polynomial $g(x)$ of degree $(n-1)$ such that $f(x) = (x-r)g(x).$  See, for example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4167303/prove-that-a-quadratic-equation-cannot-have-more-than-two-roots/4167346#4167346).

Answer (score 1):

Assume there are 3 distinct roots $r_1,r_2,r_3$. Then we have the system of equations $$lr_1^2+mr_1+n=0\\lr_2^2+mr_2+n=0\\lr_2^2+mr_2+n=0\\$$ as $r_1\neq r_2\neq r_3$ we can add and subtract lines to get $$l(r_1+r_2)+m=0\\l(r_2+r_3)+m=0\\lr_2^2+mr_2+n=0$$ but then $l(r_1+r_2)=l(r_2+r_3)$ which is onlye possible if $l=0$. If $l=0$ then $mr_1=mr_2$ which again yields that $m=0$. And so we also have $n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

This polynomial has degree 2, therefore it can not have 3 distinct roots, hence all the coefficients must be zero